# Not able to validate the plug-in in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to consume a jar created by other team (compiled using Java 8 - 64  bit) into a 32 bit application. I have added jar dependency to my project pom and able to import the classes into my project class without any issues.

Issue: When I am trying validate the plug-in in eclipse (Run > Run configuration > Plug-ins tab), seeing 
**Require-Bundle:xyz;bundle-version="0.0.0"** error.

Not sure how to fix this. I use Java 7 - 32 bit version for my project.

As jar is compiled in 64 bit version, will not work in 32 application ?

Any thoughts

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Require-Bundle:xyz` means that the plugin requires plugin `xyz` to run and it can't be found.

Most plugins are not specific to 64 or 32 bits unless they contain native code (which most don't).

Comment: I can see the jar under Referenced Libraries. That means its a runnable. right

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'runnable'

Comment: Show us the full text of the message.

Comment: Screen shot attached for the same

Comment: The screen shot seems to be saying the 'service-virtualization-api' plugin is missing.

Comment: As I have already mentioned, added jar dependency to my project pom and able to import the classes into my project class without any issues. And Jar is getting listed under Referenced Libraries.

Comment: It needs to appear in 'plugin dependencies'. The plugin must be in your target platform or in the workspace. You can't treat plugins as ordinary jars.